# I have given an image url to thumb parameter of Facebook video.Videos uploaded successfully using php sdk but it does not include the thumbnail

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

The documentation says sending the "thumb" parameter will update the thumbnail but it doesn't work. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/videos/#Creating

Is uploading thumbnails with videos using php sdk is not allowed for user videos?

Comment: It also says, _“`thumb`: The video thumbnail raw data to be uploaded and associated with a video.”_ No, a URL is not raw image data.

Comment: what should be the value of a raw image data associated with facebook video? please provide an example if you could..                                       Thank you for any feedback and help....

Comment: Go check the basic examples in the PHP SDK documentation. It has one for video upload and one for photo upload - for the `thumb` parameter it works the same way.

Comment: A facebook member stated here that this feature is currently unavailable for users. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1042527215784313/?hc_location=ufi    so i just want to know that is this still not allowed for user videos,and if allowed please tell me what is the exact value for a raw image data.